# Increasing Potentiometer Sensitivity with Passives:

Tags: potentiometer

Imagine a linear potentiometer with a 180 degree rotation range connected between +5 V and 0 V.  Turning the potentiometer from 0 to 180 degrees will sweep through the entire voltage range.  I would like to sweep through the entire (or almost the entire) range of voltages while only turning the potentiometer through part (say 45 degrees) of its total rotational range.  Obviously this can be accomplished with an op-amp, but is there a way to do this with only passive components?

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: no..............

Comment: You can modify your potentiometer by opening it and short-circuiting the range you won't use. I don't see any other options using only passive components.

Comment: Connect the pot to +15V and 0V and you may be able to get a 0V to +5V range.

Comment: @SteveG ...and burn the input after accidentally turning the pot a little bit further